# How we can copy one file from one server to other in cron

Tags: sudo, cron, scp, expect

Can anybody let me know how we can copy a file from one server to another in a cron. I know about `scp` but how we use it in a cron, since we need to pass the password.

**Edited**

I found this link [Expect script that enters a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18328/expect-script-that-enters-a-username-and-password)

Can anybody help me to do like this. I'm extremely new to Ubuntu,

Comment: you need a script

Comment: yes, i know how to copy from one server to another through terminal, but i don't how to write it in cron, since it will ask the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main options:

1. The bad one: use something like `pscp` which allows you to send the password. From `man pscp`:

   > ```
   >   -pw password
   >       Set  remote password to password. CAUTION: this will likely make
   >       the password visible to other users of the  local  machine  (via
   >       commands such as `w').
   > ```
   >
   > This will require you to have the password in the crontab file, which is a simple text file and that is not a good idea. On my Debian, with `pscp` 0.63, the password is actually masked in the output of `w` and `ps` &co but based on the man page quoted above, you cannot assume that will always be the case.
2. The better one: setup [passwordless ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/PasswordlessSSH) for the user who needs to run the `scp` command. If you don't want to do that for your regular user, just create a new user and run the crontab as that user.

Alternatively, you can set it up the other way around. Instead of having a user on machineA copying a file from machineB, have a user on machineB copy the file to machineA instead.

Yes, you can do this with an `expect` script but the same security issues will apply if you want to include the password in the script.

Comment: thanks, i will try this, sorry im not able to give upvote.